# Extract part of comma delimited string and build into a calculation

Tags: sql-server, function, loops, syntax

*I'm a SQL self-taught newbie.*
I have a column of nvarchar(max) data type called Pause_Info. It holds a string which is a date/time stamp and a duration time which are comma separated. There is no limit to iterations of entries to this column.
I believe I need a loop to iterate the string to pull the duration, convert to a numeric value, and then sum the values.

In this sample one record looks like:

| Pause_Info |
| --- |
| 2022-02-17 17:06:45,**114.44**,2022-02-17 16:15:28,**54.28** |

*(emphasis added for clarity)*

First I need to find 114.44 and 54.28, Then for this record I would need to Sum these values and create a new Column

| Pause_Duration |
| --- |
| 168.72 |

and output would show me

| Pause_Info | Pause_Duration |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-02-17 17:06:45,**114.44**,2022-02-17 16:15:28,**54.28** | 168.72 |

A second sample of data looks like this:

> 2022-02-17 16:15:28,54.28,2022-02-17 14:53:29,12.14,2022-02-17 14:49:57,48.26,2022-02-17 14:47:06,6.20,2022-02-17 14:44:58,6.12,2022-02-17 14:37:49,12.24,2022-02-17 14:32:31,6.17,2022-02-17 14:27:10,6.07,2022-02-17 14:21:53,6.05,2022-02-17 14:16:28,6.09,2022-02-17 14:11:06,6.06,2022-02-17 14:05:52,6.02,2022-02-17 14:00:40,6.06

...and I would need the end result to be a sum of all the duration values like:

| Pause_Duration |
| --- |
| 181.76 |

This is why I believe a loop is best because sometimes the column is blank but can have 1 date/time & duration entry to any number of entries.

I see that String_Split will put these into columns, but I can't see how that later solves the need to add the values. I'm not finding the correct resolution because I don't know the correct syntax to search for.

Comment: Please TAG your RDBMS, solutions will vary depending.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with the help of *string_split()* function, depending on your RDBMS - some have a native function, others have various solutions available. Split the string into rows on each comma, exclude rows that contain a date, the rest should be the numerical values to sum.

The following demo is for SQL Server

```
select Pause_info, Pause_Duration
from t
cross apply (
  select Sum(Try_Convert(decimal(6,3),value )) Pause_Duration
  from String_Split(pause_info,',')
  where not(value like '%:%')
)pd;
```

Example [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e836c36863daf05e0adf0845ee6ad53c)

Output:

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is amazing and answers my problem perfectly. Also thanks for the link for DB Fiddle, I didn't know this existed.  I am using SQL Server, I apologize for missing that in my first posting, I'm still learning how to properly reference everything.